# SQL - How to print calculated datetime result

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sqlplus -v
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0
```

```sql
select
a.user_id as user_id, 
/* convert to minutes */
(to_date(a.modified_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_date(b.modified_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) 60 * 24 as minutes
from 
(select user_id, modified_datetime, from table_name where some_conditions) a,
(select user_id, modified_datetime, from table_name where other_conditions) b,
where a.user_id = b.user_id
;
```

If `a.modified_datetime` is `'2021/10/01 13:00:00'` and `b.modified_datetime` is `'2021/10/01 12:30:00`', the result of this query would be:

```
user_id minutes
------- -------
  12345      30
```

However, I run this query via `sqlplus`, it returns

```
user_id minutes
------- -------
  12345       0
```

What's wrong with this query, or need to set some options to `sqlplus`?

Comment: Why are you storing dates  in a `varchar` column? That is a really bad idea to begin with.

Comment: No, it is stored in a `date` column.

Comment: Then the call to `to_date()` is completely useless - in fact it's wrong.  That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is stored in a date column

As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out in a comment, calling `to_date()` on a value that is already a date is incorrect, and is causing your apparent problem.

When you do:

```
to_date(a.modified_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

you are implicitly converting the date to a string using the current session NLS settings; with the still-default DD-MON-RR for example, that is really doing:

```
to_date(a.modified_datetime, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
-> to_date(to_char(a.modified_datetime), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
-> to_date(to_char(a.modified_datetime, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
-> to_date(to_char(a.modified_datetime, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
-> to_date('01-OCT-21', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
-> 0001-10-21 00:00:00
```

As both values end up as midnight, the difference between them is calculated as zero minutes.

You *could* change the NLS settings, which is fragile; or explicitly convert the the date to a string in the right format - but neither is necessary or useful.

You should not have the `to_date()` calls at all, and can just subtract the date values directly from each other:

```
select
a.user_id as user_id,
(a.modified_datetime - b.modified_datetime) * 60 * 24 as minutes
from 
(select user_id, modified_datetime from table_name where some_conditions) a,
(select user_id, modified_datetime from table_name where other_conditions) b
where a.user_id = b.user_id;
```

or using ANSI joins:

```
select
a.user_id as user_id,
(a.modified_datetime - b.modified_datetime) * 60 * 24 as minutes
from 
(select user_id, modified_datetime from table_name where some_conditions) a
join
(select user_id, modified_datetime from table_name where other_conditions) b
on a.user_id = b.user_id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14d8b4a09539c42d0b30c3fe7d345204) showing the results of the implicit conversions, and the correct output.

Comment: So, the nls_date_format of the DB is `YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS`, the query I wrote could work correctly (it has some wrong and unnecessary conversion though), but if other formats have been set, it doesn't work as I expect?

Comment: @Rohan - yes, exactly - for the session anyway, not the DB default. The fiddle shows it working with it set to that value. But don't rely on it *8-) If your session had happened to be set like that, and it had worked, then it would have broken later for someone else running it with different settings. That's why you shouldn't rely on NLS settings, except maybe for an ad hoc query, even if they happen to work OK for you.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* 30 minutes, if values really are as you stated:

```
SQL> with test (a_time, b_time) as
  2    (select to_date('2021/10/01 13:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'),
  3            to_date('2021/10/01 12:30:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
  4     from dual
  5    )
  6  select (a_time - b_time) * 60 * 24 as minutes
  7  from test;

   MINUTES
----------
        30

SQL>
```